# bitcoincore with linux (tgz) or arm linux

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, nodes, linux, raspberry-pi

I am running a node on a raspberry pi 4 model B 8gb with linux as os, should I update bitcoincore with linux (tgz) or arm linux.

Comment: Cross posted from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/23278.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Linux" binaries listed on bitcoincore.org and other download sites are for x86 (32-bit) and x86_64 (64-bit) architectures.

Raspberry Pi is an ARM-based architecture, so you need the ARM binary (32-bit if you have a 32-bit OS, 64-bit if you have a 64-bit OS; both are commonly used on Raspberry Pi).